# get count of mentions using Twitter4j api

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I want to get the count of tweets mentions a specific user. I try searching with query "@username" but I have only 15 results. Any idea?

*(Also I have not problem to use twitter Api)

```
    ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();

    cb.setOAuthConsumerKey("XXXXX");
    cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret("XXXXXX");
    cb.setOAuthAccessToken("XXXXX");
    cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("XXXXX");

    // gets Twitter instance with default credentials
    Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();

    Query query = new Query("@firefox");
    QueryResult search = twitter.search(query);
    System.out.println("count"+search.getCount());
```

Comment: I believe the `Query` object has a count property, which informs the query how many results to get back, so maybe the true result set is getting cut off by the limited number of results coming back.  Side question: Do you expect every @firefox mention ever?  What is the actual intended query?

Comment: I want to measure the influence of user. so I want all tweets that mentions a user.

Exist query count property "query.cont(1000)" bu the result is 100 for all searches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use twitter's streaming api and track the keywords or mentions.

Example: https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/blob/master/twitter4j-examples/src/main/java/twitter4j/examples/stream/PrintFilterStream.java

(Uses twitter4j).

You can count the number of times a keyword is mentioned from the time you start runnung this program. You cannot count past tweets. You have rate limitations in searching past tweets.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1